# audio player not showing on facebook share

Tags: facebook, audio, flowplayer

We are trying to share audio with image on facebook. For this we are following this example

http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/fbshare-audio.html

So now our script is

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Minimal Demo Page For Sharing Audio With Flowplayer</title>

      <meta name="medium" content="video">
      <meta name="title" content="Share Audio with Flowplayer">
      <meta name="description" content=
      "This Flowplayer demo video is coming from a page providing only the most minimal content to share audio on Facebook with Flowplayer.">
      <meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <meta name="video_height" content="30">
      <meta name="video_width" content="500">
      <link rel="video_src" href=
      "http://66.235.194.119/payroll/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf?config=%7B%27plugins%27%3A%7B%27controls%27%3A%7B%27autoHide%27%3Afalse%2C%27height%27%3A30%2C%27fullscreen%27%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%27play%27%3Afalse%2C%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%2F66.235.194.119%2Fpayroll%2Fa.wav%27%7D%7D">
      <link rel="image_src" href="http://66.235.194.119/76east/images/portfolio/thumb/item2.jpg">
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://66.235.194.119/payroll/a.html">
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Flowplayer Demos">
      <meta property="og:type" content="movie">
      <meta property="og:title" content="Share Audio with Flowplayer">
      <meta property="og:description" content=
      "This Flowplayer demo video is coming from a page providing only the most minimal content to share a video on Facebook with Flowplayer.">
      <meta property="og:video:height" content="30">
      <meta property="og:video:width" content="500">
      <meta property="og:image" content="http://66.235.194.119/76east/images/portfolio/thumb/item2.jpg">

      <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <meta property="og:video" content=
      "http://66.235.194.119/payroll/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf?config=%7B%27plugins%27%3A%7B%27controls%27%3A%7B%27autoHide%27%3Afalse%2C%27height%27%3A30%2C%27fullscreen%27%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%27play%27%3Afalse%2C%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%2F66.235.194.119%2Fpayroll%2Fa.wav%27%7D%7D">
     <link rel="canonical" href="http://66.235.194.119/payroll/a.html">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fp.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Minimal Demo Page For Sharing Audio With Flowplayer</h1>

      <p>This page demonstrates the most minimal content needed to share a video with <a href=
      "http://flowplayer.org" target="_blank">Flowplayer</a>.</p>

      <p>Share page and player on Facebook by clicking on <span class="bold"><a href=
      "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F66.235.194.119%2Fpayroll%2Fa.html">this
      link!</a></span></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But when we are sharing this on facebook, its not showing player.
What we are doing wrong?

Here is the demo of script

http://66.235.194.119/payroll/a.html

Comment: You need to use HTTPS for you links

Comment: But we don't have https connection.

Comment: Then you have to fix that